# update multiple table relation in code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need to update relation many to many between three tables.

Employee and courses and employeecourses.

When update course id in table employeecourse not done.

My model customemployee2:

```
namespace WebCourse.Models {
  public class Customemployee2
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
     public int  DistrictId { get; set; }

      public int CourseId { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Districts { set; get; }

        public List<EmployeeCourse> Courses { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeLangage> Langs { get; set; }
    } }



 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id,Customemployee2 cust2)
        {
            Employee old = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (old != null)
            {
                old.Name = cust2.Name;
                old.Email = cust2.Email;
                old.DistrictId = cust2.DistrictId;
                old.Salary = cust2.Salary;
               //what i write here to update relation in employeecourse where select course id

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                db.Employees.Include


            }
            return View(cust2);
        }
```

How to update courseid in table employeecourse?

Comment: Does your Employee has a Course collection? If yes, you need to set it before calling the SaveChanges method.

Comment: i know it must before save changes but i cannot update table employee course

Comment: Why you cannot update ? What is stopping you ? What have you tried ?

Comment: old.EmployeeCourses.Where(m => !cust2.CourseId.Contains(m.Id))
            .ToList().ForEach(EmployeeCourse => old.EmployeeCourses.Remove(EmployeeCourse));

Comment: the proplem in  !cust2.CourseId how to represent courseid in mode Customemployee2

Comment: please help me in this if possible

Comment: My humble suggestion : I think you need to isolate your problem and ask specific questions. Now i am not sure you want to know how to get the selected courses from the UI or how to save it using entity framework. Whatever it is, you should post the relevant minimal code for that specific problem and explain the specific expected behavior and the problem you are facing. Currently your question is hard to understand as none of us are not seeing your code. If you write clear questions, people will help you.

Comment: what i need is to save course id in employeecourse table